# Azure Logic App Outlook send mail action failing 403

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I tried a new Logic App with the send mail action from Outlook, but after a bit of testing i am now only getting the following back:
´ ´

```
"body": {
    "status": 403,
    "message": "Cannot send mail. Follow the instructions in your Inbox to verify your account., WASCL UserAction verdict is not None. Actual verdict is HipSend, ShowTierUpgrade.",
    "source": "127.0.0.1
}"
```

But i don't have any instructions in my Inbox that i linked in the action. 
Do i just have to wait for it to go away again?
It worked before for several requests.

Comment: Is this a brand new outlook account? Have you been able to successfully send/receive email for this account?

Comment: Yes i have its my normal account, just to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old post, but I was having the same issue and came across this thread upon Googling.

I was certain that my email addresses I am sending from and to were absolutely correct, but for some reason still got this error. 
Turns out, the confusion was related to my Azure subscriptions. I am using the **same email address** for both my work and personal accounts. I accidentally chose the Work account while connecting to Outlook (in the New Action -> Outlook Connector window), even though I was logged into Azure Portal with my Personal account.

I deleted the old Outlook Connector and re-created it - this time with the same (Personal) Account that I has used to log into Azure Portal and it works perfectly.

This might not be your problem, but just in case it is :)